# How to speed up the process using VLC and Adobe Premiere for video compilations

Tags: premiere, video-editor, adobe, vlc, playlist

I need help finding a way to speed up the process creating videos compilations using VLC and Adobe Premiere.

I have a folder with 100 videos, I'll watch the videos using VLC and I'll choose 20 of those videos to use on Adobe Premiere to create a compilation.

I tried creating a VLC playlist with those 20 videos but Premiere doesn't open the playlists.

How can I open those 20 videos out of 100 on Premiere not having to do it manually?

I have to create video compilations daily so I need to find a way to speed up the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can sort videos only in folders, then import sorted folders to premiere.
Maybe you can open playlist in video player, select all videos and copy/paste them all to new folder.

Also you can import all videos in Premiere Pro, then open folder by double-click on project panel and switch to preview mode. Then you can move mouse over clips, watch them and sort to new folder or just delete unwanted materials.
[image]
Also you can put In/Out points in video and put them all on timeline at once with needed fragments.

You can show me screencast what how do do you do it now and I will try to show how it can be in Premiere Pro with the same speed. If it can be :)

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Why not import the folder into PP and watch and sort them in PP? After all that is the whole purpose of the application.

As you watch them you add the ones you want to the end of a timeline (hit the `.` key). This is called an assembly edit. Then you can trim your selected clips later.

Comment: I don't watch the videos completely, just the first 5-10 seconds of each video. I can do it pretty fast using VLC and hotkeys, 'n' and 'space' but it's a lot of mouse clicks to do the same thing on Premiere. I save time importing all the videos directly to Premiere but it takes more time to watch them.